# Unable to query Emberjs Model when using DS.FixtureAdapter

Tags: ember.js

I'm unable to query my models.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have my store defined as

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
        revision: 12,
        adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
    });
```

And my model defined,

```
var Feature = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    parent: DS.belongsTo('SimpleTestManager.Feature'),
    DS.belongsTo('SimpleTestManager.Project'),
    children: DS.hasMany('SimpleTestManager.Feature'),
    requirements: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Feature.adapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.create();

App.Feature.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "my first feature",
        description: "some description",
        parent: null,
        project: 1,
        children:[2],
        requirements: "This is my first feature.  It has many requirements."
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "a sub feature",
        description: "some sub feature.",
        parent: 1,
        project: 1,
        children:[],
        requirements: "This is a sub feature."
    }
];
```

When I run the following in the command line

```
>>App.Features.find({id:'1'})
Error: assertion failed: Not implemented: You must override the DS.FixtureAdapter::queryFixtures method to support querying the fixture store.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks for your help in trying to figure this out.

From what I've been able to gather, the find() method calls findQuery(), which calls queryFixtures() in the FixturesAdapter.  The idea for this not being implemented is for developers to extend this to implement their own find() for stubbing out different search results.  For a basic filter on parameter, I was able to just do this.

```
////// Stub data store fixture adapter ///////
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    //adapter: 'DS.RESTAdapter',
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
        queryFixtures: function(fixtures, query, type) {
            console.log(query);
            console.log(type);
            return fixtures.filter(function(item) {
                for(prop in query) {
                    if( item[prop] != query[prop]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 30):

I managed to solve the mentioned error by using David Lai's answer, but without extending from DS.Store (the new way after Ember Data 1.0.beta.1):

```
App.FixtureAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
  queryFixtures: function(records, query, type) {
    return records.filter(function(record) {
        for(var key in query) {
            if (!query.hasOwnProperty(key)) { continue; }
            var value = query[key];
            if (record[key] !== value) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    });
  }
});


App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'Fixture'
});
```

Comment: I took me like forever to find out that this is the reason why the ember integration test suite is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that your are missing the `App` prefix you have already defined, and also the `DS` prefix for ember-data. You can also remove `Feature.adapter = EmberData.FixtureAdapter.create();`.

I've edited your code (not tested).

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Feature = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  parent: DS.belongsTo('SimpleTestManager.Feature'),
  project:DS.belongsTo('SimpleTestManager.Project'),
  children: DS.hasMany('SimpleTestManager.Feature'),
  requirements: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Feature.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: "my first feature",
    description: "some description",
    parent: null,
    project: 1,
    children:[2],
    requirements: "This is my first feature.  It has many requirements."
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "a sub feature",
    description: "some sub feature.",
    parent: 1,
    project: 1,
    children:[],
    requirements: "This is a sub feature."
}
];
```

Now to query a specific id you should use:

```
App.Feature.find(1);
```

To query by a property you can do:

```
App.Feature.findQuery({ name: "a sub feature" });
```

This should work.

Hope it helps

Comment: sorry, I forgot to change the names of things when posting.  I was using RequireJS.  For some reason I was able to call find(some id), but when calling find({property:'query string'}), this did not work.

Comment: you can try `App.Feature.findQuery({ name: "a sub feature" })`

Comment: I'm using Ember Cli these days.  using a real mock server instead of the fixture adapter.

I beleive the core problem was back then the Fixture adapter didn't have query methods supported out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the fixture adapter doesn't actually implement any query methods. If you want to find a record by its ID you can simply call `App.Feature.find(id)` but anything more complicated than that isn't supported. Even with the `DS.RESTAdapter` you have to define your own query interface on the server to make queries work properly.

Comment: This is becoming a big blocker for me.  Can someone point me in the right direction of how I can attempt to implement a query?

Comment: Ember Data simply passes the object given to it over to the server in the form of URL parameters. If you want to support queries, you'll have to make your server change its response based on the query parameters you're using.