# confused about asyc loading from direct url emberjs

Tags: ember.js

Below are my fixture adapters.
My understanding is model hook is not called on transitionTo or link-to when a model is provided.

But when same route is reached direactly by sharing or copy pasting url model hook is called.

Now when I transition by passing a model I see the city 1 and city 2 properly.

But when I copy past url the cities are not displayed. I tried `.then` and then get cities still I cannot see it. I have commented that line. I know I am doing something stupid. I did googled but couldnt figure out.

here is my jsbin: [BIN BIN BIN](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xayaqaco/2#/CO)

**Though this is similar to  [THiS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516440/slug-urls-with-ember-js?rq=1). the ans is use modelFor and then findBy. but modelFor gives model for the parent route. but in my case since its not nested routes. `this.modelFor('countries')` gives undefines and hence i cannot apply findBy on it.**

```
model: function(params) {
    this.store.find('country', params.countryCode).then(function(country) {
        console.log(country);
        //country.get('cities');
    });
}


Q.Country.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    countryCode: "CO",
    countryName: "Country",
    cities: [1, 2]
}];

Q.City.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    cityName: "city 1",
    country: 1
}, {
    id: 2,
    cityName: "city 2",
    country: 1
}];


Q.CountryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('country', params.countryCode);
    },
    serialize: function(country) {
        return {
            country_id: country.get("countryCode")
        };
    },
    afterModel: function(model) {
        console.log("after model was called");
        //this.transitionTo('cities',model);
    }
});

Q.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("countries");
    this.resource('country', {
        path: ':country_id'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `return` something from your `model()` hook. No need to use `then()` because in the model hook Ember will automatically wait for the promise to resolve.

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('country', params.country_id);
}
```

If you want to use a slug, something like this could work:

```
Q.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("countries");
    this.resource('country', {
        path: ':country_code'
    });
});

model: function(params) {
    return this.store.findQuery('country', { code: params.country_code });
}
```

Comment: No I still did not get the cities on copy pastin url to some other browser :(

Comment: Can you post your routes, too?

Comment: I guess I cannot do params.country_id. I have serialized it. so I am/will get error "You made a request for a country with id CO, but the adapter's response did not have any data."... I think deserialize is deprecated

Comment: Well in your router you specified "path: ':country_id'", no?

Comment: Of course your backend will have to respond to a request with that id.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you're saying. See my updated answer on how to use a slug in your `model` hook. Is that what you're after?

Comment: findBy is not method on store anyways i think this should work.findQuery on fixture adapter is not available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753150/unable-to-query-emberjs-model-when-using-ds-fixtureadapter

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant findQuery. I don't think there's a way of implementing what you want using `FixtureAdapter`.